# Why Lightroom not offering to choose "Edit a copy"?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

If I chose "Edit In > Photoshop CC" in normal Lightroom offered me to choose how to edit an image: edit a copy, edit this exactly image and another one option I don't remember.
Not if I try to "Edit in" Lightroom goes to Photoshop with no options and there no image copy apeared in Lightroom and no image opening in Photoshop.
After several tens of seconds Lightroom throws a message that "Can not lunch Photoshop"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightroom will not ask you this question if the image is a RAW file, because you cannot edit an original RAW file. If the image is a RAW file, the develop settings are sent to Photoshop and Photoshop will use CameraRAW (without showing the dialog) to open the image. It seems that there is a problem with your installation of Photoshop and/or CameraRAW, that's why you get the error that Photoshop could not be launched.

Comment: I'm not sure for the moment but I think that I was always using RAWs in LR and the question also appeared. Probably this question was with only option available. Bu anyway: my main concern is not the absence of this question - I can not force Lightroom to send files to Photoshop for editing properly. Any thoughts?

Comment: The CameraRAW Version of Lightroom and Ps need to match exactly for this to work. If they don't, Lr will show you the "Edit a copy"-Dialog.